# Se puede sumar un campo que resulte coincidente en un find() de mongodb? Como se podria hacer? estoy trabajando en un Buscador, gracias!

Tags: sum

los datos de mi documentos son los siguientes:
[ { id, title, descripcion, precio, estado_provicia} ]

yo ejecuto una busqueda a traves del campo title como tambien podria sumar las coincidencias por estado_provincia. para obtener tambien un grupo de donde se encuentran esos productos que busco.

finalmente pueda tener mi filtro de articulos por titulo "ya lo hice" y por otro lado obtener los estados agrupados eje:

Bolívar (4)
Carabobo (2)
Distrito Federal (3)
....

un ejemplo de como se podria hacer me bastaria yo seguiria estudiando. estoy usando mongoose, node.js y para las vistas uso ejs. muchas gracias a todos.